# Should I parse an integer to string in Java, when not necessary?

Tags: java, string, integer

I want to append an integer to a string.
Is there a difference between doing:

```
String str = "Number: " + myInt;
```

and

```
String str = "Number: " + Integer.toString(myInt);
```

In other words, should I bother using the `Integer.toString()` method, when not necessary?

***Edit:*** I am not wondering "How to convert an integer to string", but "if I am required to use a certain method, to convert".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no difference. The compiler (Oracle JVM 1.8) transform both snippets to

```
(new StringBuilder()).append("Number: ").append(myInt).toString();
```

Personally, I wouldn't use `Integer.toString()` as it adds noise to the code, and that doesn't provide clarity nor readability.

#### Edit

I made a mistake on the original answer and described that there would be a minor difference (see the answer history if you want!)

Comment: Another question would be how the `append(int)` method converts the `int` to a `String`, and hence whether or not a direct call to `Integer.toString(int)` would be better for performance.

Comment: I trust that the guys who build the JVM know about performance, and I reckon that they did this on purpose as there might be a performance improvement from using `StringBuilder.append(int)`... but I cannot comment on this, as I just don't know.

Comment: their is no reason for speculation because of of ignorance here, all the JDK source is available

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I think you're missing the compiler optimisation, which is not 'there' if in the source code. My original (and wrong) answer was based purely on the source code.

Answer (score 2):

Clarify on Augusto's answer: You can run a simple benchmark test.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Race Started"); 
    int []noArr = new int[100];
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        noArr[i] = i+1;

    String str = "";
    long startedTime = System.nanoTime();
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
        str = str + noArr[j];

    long runningTime = System.nanoTime() - startedTime;
    System.out.println("Concatenation String + int took : "+runningTime);

    startedTime = System.nanoTime();
    String str2 = "";
    for(int h=0;h<100;h++)
        str2 = str2 + Integer.toString(noArr[h]);
    runningTime = System.nanoTime() - startedTime;
    System.out.println("Concatenation String with Wrapper obj took : "+runningTime);

    startedTime = System.nanoTime();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for(int k=0;k<100;k++)
        sb.append(k);

    runningTime = System.nanoTime() - startedTime;
    System.out.println("StringBuilder took : "+runningTime);

}
```

**Summary {Time in nanoSeconds}**

Race Started (These are rough values; but you can see the huge differences)

- Concatenation String + int took : 250555
- Concatenation String with Wrapper obj took : 485413
- StringBuilder took : 98411